# pg_dump: "could not connect to server" in Rails "schema_format = :sql" migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-migrations

In my rails app (v 3.2.8), so far, I've used migrations without a problem.

I am using PostgreSQL 9.2 as the DB. I tweaked my `application.rb` to use sql instead of schema dumper (uncommented `config.active_record.schema_format = :sql`).

After that, I started to get this error on migration:

```
    $ rake db:migrate

    [ALL MIGRATION STUFF IS PRINTED HERE]

    pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "my_dev_db" failed: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
    could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
    could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (fe80::1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
    rake aborted!
    Error dumping database

I tried manually on the command line(logged in as the same user on my Mac)

<!-- language: lang-sh -->

    $ pg_dump my_dev_db > /tmp/db.sql

No problems with that...happily dumps into `/tmp/db.sql`

Why is rails having trouble with `pg_dump`? (I am on Mac OSX Lion)

===========

Adding more diagnosis information

===========

    $tail -10 /usr/local/var/postgres9.2/pg_hba.conf 

    local   all             all                                     md5
    # IPv4 local connections:
    host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
    # IPv6 local connections:
    host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
    # Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
    # replication privilege.
    #local   replication     rogert                                trust
    #host    replication     rogert        127.0.0.1/32            trust
    #host    replication     rogert        ::1/128                 trust


    $ sudo lsof -p 62444 | awk '$5 == "unix" && $NF ~ /\// { print $NF }'
    /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432

    $ ps auxw | grep post
    postgres        1403   0.0  0.0  2435492    640 s007  S+   21Oct12   0:00.05 bash
    root            1401   0.0  0.0  2498096    128 s007  S    21Oct12   0:00.02 su postgres
    rogert  62517   0.0  0.0  2426700    388 s001  R+    9:21PM   0:00.00 grep post
    rogert  62448   0.0  0.0  2481656    500   ??  Ss    8:46PM   0:00.03 postgres: wal writer process     
    rogert  62447   0.0  0.0  2481656    752   ??  Ss    8:46PM   0:00.07 postgres: writer process     
    rogert  62446   0.0  0.0  2481656   1040   ??  Ss    8:46PM   0:00.00 postgres: checkpointer process     
    rogert  62444   0.0  0.1  2481656   5368 s001  S     8:46PM   0:00.02 /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.1/bin/postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres9.2


    $ rake db:migrate --trace

    [ALL MIGRATION STUFF IS PRINTED HERE]

    /Users/rogert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails_3.2.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:393:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
    /Users/rogert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails_3.2.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
    /Users/rogert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails_3.2.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
    /Users/rogert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails_3.2.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
    /Users/rogert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails_3.2.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
    /Users/rogert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails_3.2.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
    /Users/rogert/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    /Users/rogert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails_3.2.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
    /Users/rogert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails_3.2.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
    /Users/rogert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails_3.2.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:162:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
    /Users/rogert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails_3.2.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
    /Users/rogert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails_3.2.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
    /Users/rogert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails_3.2.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
    /Users/rogert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails_3.2.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
    /Users/rogert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails_3.2.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
    /Users/rogert/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'

$sudo vi /usr/local/var/postgres9.2/postgresql.conf

[search for listen address]

# - Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = 'localhost'          # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                                        # comma-separated list of addresses;
                                        # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                                        # (change requires restart)
port = 5432                             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100                   # (change requires restart)
```

Whats weird is that if I totally remove these two lines from my rails app, the migration works. So if its a problem with TCP connections and listenting, how is the migration itself working (but won't as soon as I turn these two back on again)

1. application.rb - config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
2. In one of my migration files - t.hstore :attributes

Comment: You aren't testing the same thing; as @Tom notes, `pg_dump` will use unix domain sockets not TCP/IP by default. Try running `pg_dump -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 my_dev_Db > /tmp/db.sql` . Does that run OK?

Comment: On Mac OS X, use `sudo lsof -i -P | grep -i "listen"` to list listening TCP/IP ports. In your case you're interested in `sudo lsof -i -P | grep -i "listen" |grep postgres` or `sudo lsof -i -P | grep -i "listen" | grep 5432`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely your PostgreSQL instance is configured not to listen on TCP/IP, at least on localhost.

In `postgresql.conf` check `listen_addresses`. See [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-connection.html). Most likely it is set to `''` (the empty string) so the server only listens on UNIX domain sockets.

`psql`, `pg_dump` etc will still work if Pg isn't listening on TCP/IP because they default to connecting to a local unix domain socket. The Ruby `pg` gem is a wrapper around `libpq`, the same client library used by `psql` etc, and it also defaults to using a unix domain socket unless connection parameters are specified explicitly.

However, Rails appears to be passing an explicit IP address to `pg_dump` - causing it to try to connect over TCP/IP, which it appears Pg isn't listening on, causing the observed "connection refused" error.

Alternately, it's possible your PostgreSQL is compiled to default to a port other than 5432. The same setting is compiled in as a default in libpq, so it'll connect to the new port automatically. However, if Rails specifies an explicit port to `pg_dump` when trying to run it, it'll use that in preference to the built-in default. Check the `port` directive in `postgresql.conf`; if it is *not* commented out or set to `5432` this is probably your problem. The `port` directive is documented in the same page linked to above.

BTW, to locate `postgresql.conf` run `psql template1 -c "SHOW config_file;"` while Pg is running.

Comment: $ psql template1 -c "SHOW config_file;"
                config_file                 
--------------------------------------------
 /usr/local/var/postgres9.2/postgresql.conf
(1 row)

Comment: Also, running lsof for listening ports, shows me postgres is listening on 5432. [[postgres  62706  rogert    5u  IPv6 0xffffff8013361800      0t0  TCP localhost:5432 (LISTEN)
postgres  62706  rogert    6u  IPv4 0xffffff801bd08880      0t0  TCP localhost:5432 (LISTEN)
postgres  62706  rogert    7u  IPv6 0xffffff8013361bc0      0t0  TCP localhost:5432 (LISTEN)]]

Comment: @BVSat OK... that's the file you need to look at. I wasn't posting it because *I* needed the info, but because I thought *you* might; I often see questions where people don't know how to find `postgresql.conf`.

Comment: @BVSat Weird, it does appear to be listening on localhost:5432. This just went from a little bit odd into seriously-weird land. I'd still check the `port` and `listen_addresses` directives in `postgresql.conf`, but this is pretty weird. Maybe you've somehow got a firewall active on the loopback interface? Do you have any add-in security software, network filtering software, etc?

Comment: Thanks. But looks like postgres is listening on 5432, migration works with the schema dumper, the postgresql.conf has the listen_address as 'localhost' and port 5432 uncommented....so what else can I do go get to find out why.

Comment: Yes...I did check postgresql.conf file (as output by the command you gave me). It is in the diagnosis information in my original post.

Comment: @BVSat Ah, ok, I missed the edit. That looks perfectly fine. As for why migration with the schema dumper works - I'd say most of Rails is using the `pg` gem over a unix socket connection, so it isn't trying to use tcp/ip and thus isn't encountering the problem. Tell me: If you open Terminal.app and run `nc -l -p 5433` then open another terminal with command-N and in that one run `telnet localhost 5433`... what happens? Does the `telnet` give a `connection refused` error? Or does it work? If it works, what happens if you shut down PostgreSQL then repeat the procedure with port 5432 instead?

Comment: You can just quit Terminal to close the commands when you're done, or press `CONTROL-]` (yes, control-right-bracket) in the telnet terminal then type `quit` to close it down. `nc` will exit automatically when `telnet` disconnects, or can be closed with `control-C`. What we're testing here is whether there's an issue with *any* TCP/IP connection from a POSIX program on your machine.

Comment: Telnet on 5433 I get "telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused". Telnet on 5432, I can connect successfully. "nc -l -p 5433" I don't get anything...looks like some error. Gives me usage instructions "usage: nc [-46CDdhklnrtUuvz] [-b boundif] [-i interval] [-p source_port]
   [-s source_ip_address] [-w timeout] [-X proxy_version]
   [-x proxy_address[:port]] [hostname] [port[s]]"

Comment: @BVSat Looks like it should've been `nc -l 5433`, sorry. Anyway, the fact that you could `telnet` to `localhost` on port `5432` without stopping PostgreSQL first suggests that PostgreSQL is in fact accepting TCP/IP connections. Um. What about `psql -h localhost -p 5432 template1` ? And `psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 template1`? (they are not quite strictly the same thing).

Comment: For both psql -h localhost -p 5432 and psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432, I get the same error - "psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused. Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?"

Comment: ... but `telnet 127.0.0.1 5432` worked, printing something like `connected to 127.0.0.1`? That's *nuts*. There's no way a TCP port can be open to one program and closed to another. Again, **do you have any 3rd party security software, network software, firewall software, etc installed**?

Comment: I am terribly sorry for causing this pain -- I think I am now able to connect using "psql -h localhost 5432". It is the company software firewall. The recently installed one on my Mac and that seems to be blocking. Shutting it off then let me in. Wow! Thanks so much for your help and support. I learned a lot

Comment: @BVSat It's probably best to accept the follow-up answer I posted yesterday with the root cause; this answer led us to the real solution, but is not actually correct.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause turned out to be a 3rd party firewall package that thought that filtering connections on local loopback interfaces was a good idea.

See [the comments thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170395/pg-dump-could-not-connect-to-server-in-rails-schema-format-sql-migration/13170908#comment17923787_13170908).

Answer (score 0):

`pg_dump` from the command line would be accessing PostgreSQL using a UNIX-domain socket whereas the rails tool is trying to create a TCP connection to localhost.

Have a look at your pg_hba.conf (for me this is in /var/lib/pgsql/data/) and check that there is a line like this one, where md5 means that password authentication will be used:

```
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          md5
```

(Make sure you understand this fully if you are going to run it in a production environment!)

You can test connecting via TCP by explicitly specifying `-h localhost` on the command line when running pg_dump. Remember to restart PostgreSQL if you make any changes to pg_hba.conf.

Comment: Didn't seem to work. Strange. Firstly, I didn't know the difference between how rails was connecting and how pg_dump was connecting. If I use pg_dump with -h localhost option, I get the same error. So that rules out rails completely. But my problem remains though. So far, this is what I can see (see additional dignosis in my original post)

Comment: If it were a `pg_hba.conf` issue, the error would be a report from the Pg server that there's no `pg_hba.conf` entry for user/db/host combo. This is a `connection refused` so the issue is the server not listening. The 1st and last par are right, but the `pg_hba.conf` suggestion does not apply here.

Comment: Added a lot more diagnosis information - still the same error. I did restart the server after the changes